# Custom project types in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

When creating a new project with the .net core CLI, i can provide a -t flag with an option to specify what type of project template i want.

The standard web template is overkill for my situation, i need a basic web application template (able to accept / return JSON responses on a given port). I have been solving this, by creating a project with the console type, and adding dependencies manually, but is there a way i can save my 'lightweight-web' template, so i can reuse it?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, this should be easy using Visual Studio. I say in theory because I just tried with Visual Studio 2015 and it failed miserably when in the past, this used to work.

From vs2015, I created a new `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)` and chose the `Empty` template. Once created, I started adding stuff into my project. When happy, I selected `File-->Export Template...` from the menu and followed the steps in the wizard.

This creates a zip file of your current project which in turn, can be used as a custom project template.

Unfortunately, after trying, I was able to view my custom project template but when selecting it, it simply didn’t work.

Could it be because this feature does not work for .NET Core applications and only .NET 4.x projects? Who knows! You’d have to try!

Another (more challenging and fun) alternative would be to create your own [Yeoman Generator](http://yeoman.io/authoring/).

Another (less trivial) alternative would be to [extend the dotnet cli commands](https://wannabeegeek.com/2016/08/20/extending-dotnet-cli-commands-in-dotnet-core/). You can find a simple example here but the example is far from what you’re trying to achieve.

Considering the tooling is not yet ripe, perhaps your best bet is to create your new project(using the Empty web template). Start adding the stuff you need to make it a lightweight project.

Save that project somewhere as a template...

Next project, copy/paste from the saved template, open the solution and change a few names here and there...

At the time of writing, these might be the best options.